# Evaluate Multiple Years to Find a Leap Year Using a Boolean Utility Method

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar, leap-year

Good afternoon everyone,
I am having an issue calculating multiple leap years from a boolean utility method.  I've been told to use a loop, but have a hard time figuring out how and where to put it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class LeapYear {
      private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
          if (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 == 0) {
              return true;
          }
          if (year % 100 == 0) {
              return false;
          }
          if (year % 4 == 0) {
              return true;
          }
          else {
             return false;
         }
     }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int quitter = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    int year = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a year or -1 to quit: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();

    while (year != -1 && year < 1582) {
            System.out.print("The Gregorian calendar was not adopted until 1582, please enter a year after 1582: ");
            year = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if(year == -1) {
        negative += year;
        quitter++;
    }

    System.out.println(isLeapYear(year));
}
```

}

Comment: Just realized that the last '}' wasn't included in the code, I promise it is.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `false` if `year%100==0`?

Comment: Oh.  yes it should be.  Do you happen to have any idea how to evaluate multiple years?

Comment: You can easily correct that '}' by editing your post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a do-while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a year or -1 to quit: ");
        year = scan.nextInt();
        while (year < 1582) { 
            System.out.print("The Gregorian calendar was not adopted until 1582, please enter a year after 1582: ");
            year = scan.nextInt(); 
        } 
        if(year != -1) { 
            System.out.println(isLeapYear(year));
        } 
    }while(year!=-1);
}
```